# Queuing NSURLRequest to simulate a synchronous, blocking request

Tags: ios, multithreading, queue, nsurlrequest

I am interacting with a web-controlled hardware device. You send it a request via a URL (*e.g.*, `http://device/on?port=1` or `http://device/off?port=3`) to turn stuff on and off, and it sends back "success" or "failure". It is a simple device, however, so while it's processing a request --- *i.e.*, until it returns the status of the request that it's processing --- it will ignore all subsequent requests. It does not queue them up; they just get lost.

So I need to send serial, synchronous requests. *I.e.*, req#1, wait for response#1, req#2, wait for response#2, req#3, wait for response #3, etc.

Do I need to manage my own thread-safe queue of requests, have the UI thread push requests into one end of the queue, and have another thread pull the requests off, one at a time, as soon as the previous one either completes or times out, and send the results back to the UI thread?  Or am I missing something in the API that already does this?

Thanks!

...R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What should work is to use an `NSOperationQueue` instance, and a number of `NSOperation` instances that perform the various URL requests.

First, set up a queue in the class that will be enqueueing the requests. Make sure to keep a strong reference to it, i.e.

```
@interface MyEnqueingClass ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;

@end
```

Somewhere in the implementation, say the `init` method:

```
    _operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    _operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

You want basically a serial queue, hence the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of 1.

After setting this up, you'll want to write some code like this:

```
[self.operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"my://URLString"]];
    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    if (!responseData)
    {
        //Maybe try this request again instead of completely restarting? Depends on your application.
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            //Do something here to handle the error - maybe you need to cancel all the enqueued operations and start again?
            [self.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
            [self startOver];
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        //Handle the success case;
    }
}];

[self.operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    //Make another request, according to the next instuctions?
}];
```

In this way you send synchronous `NSURLRequest`s and can handle the error conditions, including by bailing out completely and starting all over (the lines with `-cancelAllOperations` called). These requests will be executed one after the other.

You can also of course write custom `NSOperation` subclasses and enqueuing instances of those rather than using blocks, if that serves you.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I was afraid I'd have to roll my own. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSOperationQueue class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) and also use some API which are build in on it for example [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).